# Send a part of an image to be rendered on canvas

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, html5-canvas

I am making a game in which the player can move around a 10,000 by 10,000 grid.

However, they will not always see this 10,000 by 10,000 grid, but just a small fraction based on their screen size. So say if the user screen is 2000 pixels by 1000 pixels wide, and they are currently at 5,000 x 5,000 (The center of my grid).

How can the server send just part of the map to fit this 2000 by 1000 pixel area?

[Image of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHHR4.png)

Comment: What is the server side code written in?

Comment: I am using node JS With express and socket io

Answer (score 2):

Break the image of the map down into [tiles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Games/Techniques/Tilemaps). It's how, e.g., Google Maps does it.

Comment: I cannot do that. My map is 10,000 by 10,000 pixels, and the map should move 1 pixel up or down when the player moves.

Comment: How does that prevent you from cutting up your map into 100 1000 by 1000 images? Tile maps do not have to consist of repeating tiles. On Google Maps each tile is different.

Comment: I mean, if my user is moving 60 a second times, 1 pixel up. Each frame, that's alot of tiles right?

Comment: If your tiles are 1000 by 1000 pixels then moving the player up by 60 pixels will either leave the player on the same tile or move them up one tile.